# Proving A 2-Dimensional Manifold

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am stuck on how to prove that this is a 2D manifold. I would really appreciate a stp-by-step explanation on showing how:

Let $\gamma = (0,1)\times(0,2\pi)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ be given by $\gamma(u,v) =  (u\cos(v), u\sin(v), v)$

Let $M = \{\gamma(u,v) \in\mathbb{R}^3: 0<u<1, 0< v < 2\pi\}$

How do we prove that $M$ is a smooth, 2D manifold with the information?

Comment: You want to show that $\gamma$ is a chart and that it covers $M$ given $u$ and $v$

Comment: Try to imgaine what the surface is and calculate the Jacobian

Comment: Then show $\gamma$ also admits an inverse.

Comment: @IAmNoOne so the jacobian will be a 2 column by 3 row, correct?

Comment: @IAmNoOne why wouldn't it be a 2 by 3, as we only have two variables and 3 equations?

Comment: @IAmNoOne and from here, is it correct to check to see if the ranks of the subminors are 0?

Comment: Sorry I said it too fast. It will be 3 by 2. To check the rank, just note the columns will be linearly independent. You will need the cross product to show it is nonzero.

Comment: @IAmNoOne what if we are to find $T_{C}M$, the tangent space at c=(1,0,0,2)? How are we to do this if there are only two variables?

Comment: A tangent plane requires only two vectors.